# How can I manage asynchronous in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I am now getting trouble that I don't know how to use asynchronous for doing this.
I have a file call "jsonFileData.js", here it is:

```
// jsonFileData.js
var fs = require('fs'),
    Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter,
    csvConverter = new Converter();

function jsonFile(filename) {

    csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function(jsonObj)     
    return jsonObj;
    });
    fs.createReadStream('../csv_parse/' + filename + '.csv').pipe(csvConverter);                                 
}

module.exports = {
    language: jsonFile('language'),
};
```

Another file call "main.js"

```
// main.js
var jsonFile = require('./jsonFileData');

console.log(jsonFile.language);
```

When I run "main.js", It appears "underdefined". How can I make the "var jsonFile = require('./jsonFileData');" run completely before starting to print out the result "jsonFile.language"?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Notice that your `jsonFile` function does not have a return value. That is why the module is undefined.

Comment: This type of question is asked at least 10 times per day here.  I'd suggest you do some searching on "async node.js return" and go read some of the hundreds of answers and articles.  The short answer is that asynchronous callbacks are called some time in the future, while the other synchronous code continues to run.  Thus, the ONLY place you can consume the result of an asynchronous function is IN the callback that signals its completion.  You can't treat your function as synchronous and return the value if the value is obtained asynchronously.

Comment: Also, you need to understand that a `return` statement inside a callback function ONLY returns from that callback and that return value goes back into the bowels of the async operation, not back to any of your code.  It does not return from the outer function.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for all you guys helping me. But I found out the way for using 'bluebird' and 'then' for treating this. But is it right for using it? Because I try to use it, but it's got trouble. How's your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your async callback is not right. Compare with the changes I made below.

```
// jsonFileData.js
var fs = require('fs'),
Converter = require('csvtojson').Converter,
csvConverter = new Converter();

function jsonFile(filename,callback) {

  csvConverter.on("end_parsed",function(jsonObj) {    
    return callback(null, jsonObj);
   });
  fs.createReadStream('../csv_parse/' + filename + '.csv').pipe(csvConverter);                                 
 }

module.exports = {
  language: jsonFile
};
```

And in your `main.js` file:

```
// main.js
var jsonFile = require('./jsonFileData');

jsonFile.language('language', function(err, jsonObj){
   if(err){
     console.log(err);
     return;
   }
   console.log(jsonObj);
   console.log("Hello World!"); // Edit based on comment
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want to add the line 'console.log('Hello World')' at the end of main.js. That's I want it print out the result jsonObj's data and then print out the 'Hello World'. But when i try to test your code, It print out the 'Hello World' first, and then print out the result of jsonObj. So how can I manage for print out the jsonObj first, and then 'Hello World'. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: See my edit above, I added a console log statement immediately after the `console.log(jsonObj)`. Everything you want to do after the file is loaded has to go inside of the callback function, not outside.